# How to create a utility class to reference multiple components without creating another component

Tags: lightning-web-components

Previously, I've used Aura's ltng:require to reference a static resource containing multiple js functions**. Here I'm following the d3 example from the docs:

```js
import util from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/util';
import { loadScripts } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class Test extends LightningElement {
  renderedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
      loadScripts(this, util + '/util.js'); // <-- this isn't working and returning undefined
    ])
    .then(() => { //initialize })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

So the issue is that *I am not able to load the util functions* (excuse the typo earlier about files) despite following the docs for the d3 library - I don't want to create another js file within the component, as I want to use the util library for multiple components. I feel like there would be an easier way to do this.

Comment: what is the prob you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been done pretty easily before using the d3 library. Check out the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library). This question is a duplicate btw. [It has been asked before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252826/feasibility-to-import-entire-lwc-classes-to-access-api-methods).

Basically:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import UtilityLWC from 'c/UtilityLWC'; // doesn't work
// import * as util from c/UtilityLWC; // also doesn't work
// import { foo, bar } from c/UtilityLWC; // nope

export default class ConsumerLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  connectedCallback() {
    // None of these work
    UtilityLWC.foo();
    UtilityLWC.bar();
    // util.foo();
    // util.bar();
    // foo();
    // bar();
  }

}

    import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class UtilityLWC extends LightningElement {

  @api
  foo() {
    console.log('foo from UtilityLWC');
  }

  @api
  bar() {
    console.log('bar from UtilityLWC');
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey @sfdc-pup, I looked through these docs but IDK why I get undefined when I follow the docs. The file type is .zip inside the library it is just an object literal with function definitions util = { 
  log: function(){
    console.log('hello world');
  }
}
Thanks for the replies.

Comment: i edited my answer. basically this question is a duplicate so i posted the solution some other guy used and i use too.

Comment: @sfdc-pup, I noticed in the link to the question provided an entirely different approach. Thanks, at the bottom it says how to use the shared js lwc. I think you posted the question, not the solution but, you are right, it is simple and exactly what I need!